# How to run sql script from webdriverIO Tests

Tags: selenium-webdriver, mocha.js, ui-automation, webdriver-io, webdriver-io-v4

I wanted to fetch the data from the database and use that data to verify from my application. I got code to connect DB and fetch it but this is with individual database.js file only. The problem here is how do I call
connection.query from my test case

**background**
Using webdriverIO/Mocha framework

**my Test case look like this**

```
it(" DB Testing", () => {
  console.log("DB TEST STARTED")

//I want call DB query and fetch the data, but I don't know how to do it.
db.query ('SELECT email FROM <table name> WHERE user_id =40929',[], function(results){
    if (results){
        console.log("RESULT"+results[0].email);
    }
    else{
        console.log(error);
    }
    
})


console.log("DB TEST Ended")
}
```

**database.js file**

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'me',
  password : 'secret',
  database : 'my_db'
});

connection.connect();

connection.query('SELECT email from productSolution', function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log('The solution is: ', results[0].email);
});

connection.end();
```

I did try running database.js file it worked, i mean able to fetch data from Database. But the problem here is to call this query from my test case.